# Using the == operator to test two items in a struct

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading

I currently have this struct overloading the == operator to test for equality of key values when creating a hash table via a linked list. It *IS* successfully helping to place the key and values in the right place. The program I am writing places 70 random numbers between 1 and 200 in the hash table and if the same random number is generated again it will either remove it or replace it. Bellow is my struct with the == operator as it currently is.

```
struct RecordType 
{ 
    int key = 0; int value = 0;
    //Recor
    bool operator==(const RecordType& source)
    {
        return (key == source.key); // this works for keys
    }
};
```

I want to make it test for both keys and values, so I tried the following:

```
struct RecordType 
{ 
    int key = 0; int value = 0;
    //Recor
    bool operator==(const RecordType& source)
    {
        return (key == source.key || value == source.value); // Not working
    } 
};
```

I was hoping this would work but the program just ends up lagging indeffinitely. Any suggestions? Should I make two or would && work better? (This is a chained hashing program)

Comment: `(key == source.key || value == source.value)` should probably be `(key == source.key && value == source.value)` but without a [mre] that's just an educated guess.

Comment: What exactly is the the condition for two objects of type `RecordType` to be equal? Also define "not working". [Edit] and show some code that demonstrates that it is "not working".

Comment: BTW: it's probably time now to get familiar with your debugger, a tool that is exactly what you need for... debugging these kind of problems.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to make it test for both keys **and** values

Note the emphasis on the **and** in the above quoted question description. According to your description you want to check for both keys **and** values while according to your given code you're actually checking for both keys **or** values.

Thus to solve this, replace `||` with `&&` as shown below:

```
//-----------------vv------------------------->changed || with && 
(key == source.key && value == source.value)
```